# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function getRequestedRouteName() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

I have installed Magento CE 1.9.1 and i have an error on "save order" page after a order is been send, The order seems fine in admin, but no email is been send.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getRequestedRouteName() on a non-object in //public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 226

Action.php:

```
/**
 * Retrieve full bane of current action current controller and
 * current module
 *
 * @param   string $delimiter
 * @return  string
 */
public function getFullActionName($delimiter='_')
{
    return $this->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName().$delimiter.
        $this->getRequest()->getRequestedControllerName().$delimiter.
        $this->getRequest()->getRequestedActionName();
}
```

PS: no core files has been edited !

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you installed any patches recently?