# PHP Fatal Error in Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I keep having this problem flood by error_log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRequestedRouteName() on a non-object in /home/bullion/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 226

Here is the code snippet from lines 224-229

```
public function getFullActionName($delimiter='_')
{
    return $this->getRequest()->getRequestedRouteName().$delimiter.
        $this->getRequest()->getRequestedControllerName().$delimiter.
        $this->getRequest()->getRequestedActionName();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840977/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getrequestedroutename-on-a-non) - I can't vote to close this one, as the other one doesn't have any answers - but it's the exact same problem, and I'd imagine that focusing attention on one of them rather than both would be beneficial.

Comment: I'm new here and didn't see that.. I guess we can close this one if needed.. I'd like to get some type of answer though.